# Calculations in a dynamically added rows using jquery

Tags: jquery

Iam trying to do a calculation in a page. It is calculating qty * price and write to amount field. And showing the totals of the amount field as GRAND TOTAL.

This is all working fine. Now in the bottom i have a link if users can dynamically add rows. After creating dynamic rows its not taking the calculations. Iam new to jquery and iam not able to find why its having problem. Can anyone pls help me with the same.

My HTML is below

```
<form id='cart1' name='cart' method='post' class='single' action='manual_items_poverification_save.php?tender_id=140586' ><h2 align="center">ADD PRODUCTS</h3>
<div class="clone_row">

<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" id="table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
        <td width="5%">SlNo</td>

        <td width="25%">Prod Description</td>

        <td width="5%">Qty</td>

        <td width="5%">Units</td>

        <td width="10%">Currency</td>

        <td width="4%">Price/Unit</td>
        <td width="4%">Total</td>

        <td width="4%">Del</td>

    </tr>
</thead>
<div class="clone_row">
    <tr class="product">

        <td width="5%"><input size='1' type="text" name="slno[]" /></td>

        <td width="25%"><textarea name="item_description[]"></textarea></td>

        <td width="5%"><input size="2" class="qty" name="qty[]" type="text"></td>

            <td width="15%"><input size="15" id="item_units[]" name="item_units[]" type="text"></td>

        <td width="10%"><select class="currency-select" id="currency_change[]" name="currency_change[]">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="USD" data-price="1">USD</option>
            <option value="INR" data-price="67.434191">INR</option>
            <option value="GBP" data-price="0.704985">GBP</option>
            <option value="EUR" data-price="0.91118">EUR</option>
            <option value="SGD" data-price="1.386987">SGD</option>
            <option value="AUD" data-price="1.347597">AUD</option>
            <option value="CAD" data-price="1.342118">CAD</option>
            <option value="CHF" data-price="0.997145">CHF</option>
            <option value="JPY" data-price="112.6934">JPY</option>
            <option value="MYR" data-price="4.129541">MYR</option>
            <option value="ZAR" data-price="15.43258">ZAR</option>
            </select></td>

        <td width="4%"><input size="8" class="price" id='price' name="price_unit[]" type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="amount" id="amount"></td>
        <td class="delTD"><input class="delINP hidden" type="checkbox" /></td>
        GRAND TOTAL:<input type="text" class="total" id="total">

    </tr>

    </div>

</table>

</div>

<br><br>
<a href="#" id="add_more">Add More Rows</a>

<table><tr><td><input value="--Update Data--" type="submit"></td><td></td></tr></table>

</form>
```

My jquery is below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){

    update_amounts();
    $('.price').change(function() {
        update_amounts();
    });
        $('.qty').change(function() {
        update_amounts();
    });
});

function update_amounts()
{
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('.product').each(function() {
        var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
        var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
        var amount = (qty*price)
        //alert(amount);
        sum+= amount;
        $(this).find('.amount').val(amount); 
    });
    $('.total').val(sum);
    //just update the total to sum  

}
});

</script>
<style>
.hidden{display:none;}
.row-highlighted{background-color:red;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
$(document).on('click', '.delINP', function(){
    var rr = $(this).closest('tr');
    rr.addClass('row-highlighted');
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')){
            if (rr.hasClass('newTR')) rr.remove();
    }else{
        rr.removeClass('row-highlighted');
        rr.find('td.delTD input').prop('checked',false);
    }
});

$("#add_more").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clone = $("#table tbody tr:last").clone();
        clone.addClass('newTR');
    clone.find('td.delTD input').removeClass('hidden');
        $("#table tbody").append(clone);
});
$("#submit").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($("#cart1").serialize());
});
}
</script>
```

FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/1qbsp3b1/

Comment: Can anyone help me on this plsss. Or its kind of beyond the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change jquery "change" event for added dynamic add dom in html.
you need to use "on" event in jquery for that like as per below.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        update_amounts();
        $(document).on('change','.price',function(){
            update_amounts();
        });

        $(document).on('change','.qty',function(){
            update_amounts();
        }); 
    });
```

this will definitely help you case.

If you going to register event for dynamic dom then it must be re-register your event or call with “on”.

below link with you reference

https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```js
// Execute once document is ready.
$(function () {
  // Execute when the #add button is clicked.
  $("#add").click(function () {
    // Clone the #master, remove the id from the clone and append it to body.
    $("#master").clone().removeAttr("id").appendTo("tbody");
  });
  // Attach a click event handler on table, which listens for clicks on .del.
  $("table").on("click", ".del", function () {
    // Remove the parent TR tag completely from DOM.
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });
  // Attach input change event handler on table, which listens for clicks on input.
  $("table").on("input", "input", function () {
    // For every row...
    $("tbody tr").each(function () {
      // Cache the value of the current row.
      $this = $(this);
      // Do this only if this is not the master row.
      if (this.id != "master")
        // Set the value of .Amount here (making sure you set it to integer multiplying two values).
        $this.find(".Amount").val(+$this.find(".Quantity").val() * +$(this).find(".Rate").val());
      // Set the totals to 0.
      $("#total_amt, #total_qty").text(0);
      // For every .Amount, collect the values and sum it and add it to #total_amt unless it's empty.
      $(".Amount").each(function () {
        if (this.value != "")
          $("#total_amt").text(parseInt($("#total_amt").text()) + parseInt($(this).val()));
      });
      // For every .Quantity, collect the values and sum it and add it to #total_qty unless it's empty.
      $(".Quantity").each(function () {
        if (this.value != "")
          $("#total_qty").text(parseInt($("#total_qty").text()) + parseInt($(this).val()));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
th {text-align: left; font-weight: 600;}
table {border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #999; width: 100%;}
table td,
table th {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
table input {max-width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
table td:first-child input {width: 50px;}
#master {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sl No</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="master">
      <td><input type="text" class="Sl" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="Product" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="Quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="Rate" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="Amount" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="&times;" class="del" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Total</th>
      <th><span id="total_qty">0</span> Items</th>
      <th></th>
      <th><span id="total_amt">0</span> $</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add New" id="add" />
```

Comment: Thank you Praveen for the time.

Comment: Sure... The key part is using `.on()`.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Can you add comments to this code step by step? That's part of what's happening. It's easy for someone new like me to understand. thank you very much

Comment: @TipVisor Sure thing... Let me do it.

Comment: @TipVisor Check now.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but still, there are a couple of problems with your code:

- ***Do not wrap a `$(document).ready(fn)` handler in a `$(window).load(fn)`***

  By doing so, you are first waiting for the `window` object to be fully initialized, then you are checking if the DOM has finished loading - either one is sufficient for the same purpose.
- Use [event delegation with `.on()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added DOM elements.

  By using event delegation, you force a direct parent of the element to listen to a *bubbled* event from deep within it. If a bubbled event is encountered, the event handler will be attached accordingly.

  Quoting from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

  > Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers

[**Forked working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/wze1h1rz/)