# How can I get my formset data to refresh after a cell is updated with an integer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have been playing around with this for a couple of days and made a little more progress today.  I am simply trying to add values when a user enters them in a table.  This code kind of works.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='-line_item_total']").on('keyup', function(){
        var total = 0;
        console.log('hello1');
        // on every keyup, loop all the elements and add all the results
        $("input[name$='-line_item_total']").each(function(index, element) {
            var val = parseFloat($(element).val());
            if( !isNaN( val )){
               total += val;
            }
        });
        $("#id_total_total").val(total);
    });
  });
```

The table in question is a dynamic one in that the user can enter as many rows as they want.  The problem I'm having is that only when the user updates the first line item that starts with -line_item_total do the values all referesh.  What I'm trying to achieve is any time any of the rows that end with -line_item_total are updated then the entire column is recalculated.  As stated, this code works in that it does seem to see all of the values and recalculate if the user goes back the original cell and updates the initial value but that's not exactly what I'm hoping to achieve. If there is a better way to achieve this I'm open to that too.  I'm confused because all of the cells do end with -line_item_total so I would expect the recalculation to happen every time based on the code I've provided but it's not working that way.  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to my question via this SO...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787479/calculations-in-a-dynamically-added-rows-using-jquery

Here's my final code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup',"input[name$='-line_item_total']",function(){
        update_total();
    });
  });

  function update_total()
  {
    var total = 0;
    $("input[name$='-line_item_total']").each(function(index, element) {
        var val = parseFloat($(element).val());
        if( !isNaN( val )){
             total += val;
          }
        });
        $("#id_total_total").val(total);
  }
</script>
```